# laravel "get" parameter not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a bit of difficulty with something simple.

If I visit test.dev/test/1, I get the following error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Controller method not found.

my controller

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex($id)
    {
        return View::make('test.index');
    }

}
```

If I remove The $id from the controller and take the 1 out of the url it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: thank you very much that worked can you tell me whats wrong with this controller i was using Route::controller('test', 'TestController');

Comment: I am not sure how the Route::controller works I never used it, but when having troubles with routes I suggest you run the `php artisan routes` command it lists all the registered routes in your app, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've missed the parameter in your route declaration. Check the docs for [Route Parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters).

Check if your route is declared properly. It should look something like this

```
Route::get(test/{id}, TestController@getIndex)
```

Notice the `{id}` - that's the parameter you are passing to the `getIndex()` method.